# How to get a grouped bar plot in Python in which one of the bar is stacked and the others are not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which looks as follows:

```
World   Coal    Oil and natural gas Nuclear Renewables  Storage Electricity networks
2015    79.6    79.8    28.4    309.9   1.6 316.8
2016    70.9    83.2    33.7    318.3   2.5 327.9
2017    65.8    77.2    36.9    325.9   3.1 318.6
2018    64.7    64.5    34.0    359.0   4.7 310.3
2019    62.2    67.4    34.8    393.2   4.6 291.8
2020    56.4    55.3    39.5    418.4   6.2 291.6
2021    51.6    67.0    43.7    445.8   9.4 308.1
2022    48.2    70.8    49.3    471.7   18.3    318.2
```

`df.to_dict()` is as shown below:

```
{'Coal': {2015: 79.6,
  2016: 70.9,
  2017: 65.8,
  2018: 64.7,
  2019: 62.2,
  2020: 56.4,
  2021: 51.6,
  2022: 48.2},
 'Oil and natural gas': {2015: 79.8,
  2016: 83.2,
  2017: 77.2,
  2018: 64.5,
  2019: 67.4,
  2020: 55.3,
  2021: 67.0,
  2022: 70.8},
 'Nuclear': {2015: 28.4,
  2016: 33.7,
  2017: 36.9,
  2018: 34.0,
  2019: 34.8,
  2020: 39.5,
  2021: 43.7,
  2022: 49.3},
 'Renewables': {2015: 309.9,
  2016: 318.3,
  2017: 325.9,
  2018: 359.0,
  2019: 393.2,
  2020: 418.4,
  2021: 445.8,
  2022: 471.7},
 'Storage': {2015: 1.6,
  2016: 2.5,
  2017: 3.1,
  2018: 4.7,
  2019: 4.6,
  2020: 6.2,
  2021: 9.4,
  2022: 18.3},
 'Electricity networks': {2015: 316.8,
  2016: 327.9,
  2017: 318.6,
  2018: 310.3,
  2019: 291.8,
  2020: 291.6,
  2021: 308.1,
  2022: 318.2}}
```

I am able to create a stacked bar plot using this entire data using

```
colors = ["black","gray","red","green","blue","yellow"]
df.plot(kind = "bar", stacked = True, color = colors)
```

The stacked bar plot is as shown below:
[image]

However, I'd like to have three separate bars for Generation, Storage and Electricity Networks. Generation here refers to data for Coal, Oil and natural gas, Nuclear and Renewables. How am I able to do it using matplotlib in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot first the stacked bars right aligned and then, on the same axes, the remaining bars left aligned.
You can then fix the legend to your liking.

```
ax = df.iloc[:,:4].plot.bar(stacked=True, align='edge', width=-.2, color=colors[:4])
df.iloc[:,4:].plot.bar(ax=ax, align='edge', width=.4, color=colors[4:])

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
labels = [f'Generation ({l})' if i < 4 else l for i,l in enumerate(labels)]
ax.legend(handles, labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I have accepted the answer. I just want to confirm that the width cannot be greater than 0.2 (negative) in the first case because the bar will move in negative x-direction. Is that correct?

Comment: The sum of the absolute widths should not exceed 1, otherwise the bars will overlap. So -.333 and .666 is fine and results in a chart without gaps. See the docs on [`bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) for details.